# Can I ask Kubuntu related questions here as well?

Tags: discussion, scope, derivatives

Or Xubuntu as well?  Is this *buntu independent?

Answer (score 15):

Of course you can.

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu *is* Kubuntu. The flavors are just different sets of starting packages.

Answer (score -11):

I think you should start a separate Kubuntu StackExchange, or use another more general site. This site was created very specifically to address Ubuntu questions; allowing questions about Ubuntu derivatives will make the site harder to use.

Also, if this site is successful, we will create an Ubuntu-specific design for it, which might make Kubuntu questions feel out of place(?).

Comment: Why? What separates a Kubuntu system from a regular Ubuntu sytem, except the list of installed packages?

Comment: What separates an apple from an orange?

Human beings do not differentiate Ubuntu from Kubuntu in their minds by a list of packages. As far as normal users are concerned, Ubuntu is not Kubuntu, end of story. This is a site for Ubuntu users to ask and answer questions about Ubuntu; it's completely free to create another site where Kubuntu users can ask and answer questions about Kubuntu. Mixing the two will confuse some users; separating the two will lead to less confusion. What is objectionable?

Comment: Well, while I do see your point, I would argue that Kubuntu isn't really separate from Ubuntu. Apart from using the same packages from the same repositories it is also one of the predefined Ubuntu tasksel installs.

Comment: I support andol: you can get "Kubuntu" just by installing kubuntu-desktop besides ubuntu-desktop and then decide between "Kubuntu" and "Ubuntu" during login (or login into both sessions at the same time).

Comment: David, your sarcasm was inadequately tagged. Then again, with the Code of Conduct, people have gotten used to getting straight answers.

Comment: Broam, I am not being sarcastic. Do you mean my question about apples and oranges? It was rhetorical, but not sarcastic.

Comment: I do feel that David is correct, even if partially. Most newbies depend on the UI and switching between various *buntu flavours changes a lot.