# Discouraging "Ubuntu" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Figured I might as well be the first to bring this up...

Some relation to but not the same issue as: [What ubuntu versions are covered?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/24/what-ubuntu-versions-are-covered)

At time of writing, there are currently [nine instances of the "Ubuntu" tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) on the site.

To me, this makes roughly as much sense as tagging a StackOverflow question with 'programming'.

I'm going to propose discouraging use of the "Ubuntu" tag. If a question is specifically tied to a particular variant, of course, it should be tagged with that variant (e.g. Kubuntu), but for "Ubuntu Prime" or general questions not tied to a particular variant, it's redundant.

Comment: This should also apply to tags like kubuntu.

Comment: @Andrew: Why? I expect to see plenty of questions, particularly UI-related, that are pretty specific to Kubuntu/Xubuntu/etc.. They ought to be tagged as such.

Comment: @Andrew I agree with you. While some might say that they can be tagged as Gnome, KDE etc but I do not think this is really user friendly. This is a tricky problem.

Comment: @Shubhkarman: I don't see how user friendliness enters into it. We're not requiring users know the right tags before they submit questions. Community members can and will add and modify tags as appropriate, just as on other SE sites. The tags aren't for the people asking the question, they're for people answering it, and for people in the future looking for answers to similar questions.

Comment: So this means, questions should be tagged with gnome, kde, xfce, etc., rather than kubuntu, xubuntu etc.?

Comment: I feel the tag should not be allowed at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is good advice for any site. No use in filling the site with redundant, implied tags. `Ubuntu` tags removed.

Comment: Is this removal something that must be done manually from time to time? I'm wondering because there are presently 13 questions tagged with "ubuntu".

Comment: I manually removed some more, but I agree with moberley. These tags shouldn't be allowed at all.

Comment: They still persist!  In fact, there is one tag that is simply named `ubuntu`