# No tag for ubuntu on askubuntu.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface

I want to  change [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223081/how-to-backup-full-system-as-iso) the kubuntu tag to ubuntu. But i could not find it.

Is it lost? Or I'am blind.

Comment: Ubuntu is implied on Ask Ubuntu, use the version tag (ie 18.04) instead. Also you are free to create any tag you like at your reputation https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags so you can add it if you want.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: Related: [Discouraging “Ubuntu” tags](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/34/816190)

Comment: @MarkKirby IIRC [tag:ubuntu] was made a synonym of [tag:ubuntu-desktop] and then [got blacklisted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/875/816190) in the past, i.e., you can't create [tag:ubuntu] tag.

Comment: @Kulfy Seems you are correct, I just tried to create it and got "The 'ubuntu-desktop' tag is not allowed." good find I did not know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

If you are posting on Ask Ubuntu, it's implied you're using Ubuntu or an official variant of Ubuntu.

That's why we don't have an ubuntu tag - it's superfluous.  Use the version tag to identify your version of Ubuntu if the question is specific to that version, and only tag *variants* of Ubuntu if you are not using Ubuntu Desktop or Server - otherwise it's implied.

Comment: If your question is specific about the default Ubuntu flavour's desktop, you could also use [tag:gnome] (on 18.04 or newer) or [tag:unity] (16.04 or older). Don't add it if the desktop environment is rather irrelevant to your question though.

Comment: I've been away for a bit, have we really decided that this is a valid use of version tags?

Comment: @terdon In this instance the OP did state they had 18.04 in the question, so adding that tag seems appropriate.

Comment: @MarkKirby sure, but there has [long been a debate](https://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=version+tags) on whether or not that should be done by tags or simply by mentioning the version in the question. There has never been a very clear conclusion, but I always thought the consensus was leaning towards only using version tags for things that are version-specific (e.g. "what version of gnome ships with 18.04"), so you wouldn't add the tag just because you happen to be using a version unless your question is specifically about _that_ version. It is certainly not a subject everyone agrees on.

Comment: @terdon Ah yes now you mention it, I remember that. It is an interesting debate. This is really old be still relevant for any interested readers: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1514/when-should-we-use-the-versions-tags/1521#1521