# Is this a good place to ask questions about official derivatives of Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What ubuntu versions are covered?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/24/what-ubuntu-versions-are-covered)

Such as Kubuntu? or the other official derivatives. Is there any rules on this or opinions?

As a former Ubuntu user, and a Kubuntu user I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes!

We don't much like questions about *unofficial* derivatives, but questions such on [kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu), [xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu) and [lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lubuntu) (and probably some others I forgot...) are actively encouraged.